# Spring can't find my html page

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring. I am trying to do something simple, just make spring read one of my html pages. I know it is very basic, but i already tried many tutorials and can't make it work.

In the image below is my project folders

[Project Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk6iT.png)

Here is my controller

```
package com.springbootrecipes.controllers;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Controller
public class RecipeController {

    @RequestMapping("/ola")
    public String olaa() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String ola() {
        return "/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/ei")
    @ResponseBody
    public String ei() {
        return "Um ola pra quem ta chegando";
    }

}
```

And here is my main class

```
package com.springbootrecipes.springbootrecipes;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.springbootrecipes.controllers"})
public class SpringbootRecipesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootRecipesApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I also added my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.springboot-recipes</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-recipes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>springboot-recipes</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M1</version>
    </parent>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repository.spring.release</id>
            <name>Spring GA Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.spring.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

I created a responseBody and Spring found whats is writen on there. but when I tried to reach a page, Spring can't find that. Spring is mapping my class..

```
2018-03-27 09:49:26.874  INFO 4047 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/ola]}" onto public java.lang.String com.springbootrecipes.controllers.RecipeController.olaa()
2018-03-27 09:49:26.875  INFO 4047 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.springbootrecipes.controllers.RecipeController.ola()
2018-03-27 09:49:26.876  INFO 4047 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/ei]}" onto public java.lang.String com.springbootrecipes.controllers.RecipeController.ei()
```

Comment: Did u try keeping your `index.html` in static folder. Also, you need to specify the full path in order to access the page i.e `/index.html`

Comment: What is in your application.properties?

Comment: whats the response if you go to `http://localhost:8080`?

Comment: I got an 404 error --> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available


@ansh ok, if i put the html file on static folder and set the path to /index.html, it works. But why can't i use it in templates folder?

   user6690200, application.properties is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your `thymeleaf` dependency in your `pom.xml`
You should use the dependency which `spring-boot` provides for `thymeleaf` autoconfiguration.

insert:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

instead of:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need view resolver here

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5")
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {

        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");        
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {

        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf view resolver")
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return viewResolver;
    }    

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }
}
```

Or if you want spring boot auto take care of it then use thymeleaf stater

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

instead of

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

thymeleaf stater will take care of view resolver you don't need to define viewresolver bean